# Implication in local noetherian domain of Krull's dimension 1.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $(A,m)$ be a local noetherian domain with Krull dimension $1$. Let $k$ be the field $A/m$.
>
> I'm trying to prove that if $m/m^2$ has dimension $1$ as a $k$-vector space, then every ideal $I$ of $A$ is a power of $m$.

I started the argument with; If $I=A$ then trivially $I=m^0$ and we're done. Otherwise it must be
$I\subset m$ since every element of $A\setminus m$ is invertible;
but I can't think of a way to use the hypothesis from this point.

Could someone sketch a way to prove this? Thank in advance.

Comment: Well, it has to be a power $\mathfrak{m}^k$. Can you think of a way to find $k$?

Comment: @Hoot That it has to be a power of $m$ is what I want to prove. I feel like it has to be easy, but I just don't see it. I've been thinking about it a while but reasoning picking a point $i\in I$ leads me nowhere.

Comment: I guess what's most natural depends on what's available to you. Do you know Krull's intersection theorem? It says that $\bigcap_i \mathfrak{m}^i = 0$. My point is that you need to at least get some candidate $k$ from the initial data.

Comment: @Hoot I don't know Krull's theorem. Just looked for it. In any case I can't think of a candidate to the power.

Comment: I'll try to think of whether there's an easier way. Krull is a good fact to know, though. Anyway, if $I \neq 0$ then there is some $k$ such that $I \subseteq \mathfrak m^k$ but $I \not\subseteq \mathfrak{m}^{k+1}$. If this thing is going to be true then we must have $I = \mathfrak{m}^k$, so this is at least something to hold onto. Can you prove that $\mathfrak{m}$ is principal, by the way?

Comment: @Hoot You're using Krull's intersection theorem when saying that $I\subset m^k$ but $I\not\subset m^{k+1}$ for some $k$ right? But how you deduce from here that $I=m^ k$? This implication is a part of an exercise that shows equivalence between several conditions, one of which is that $m$ is principal.

Comment: I'm not deducing that $I = \mathfrak{m}$, I'm saying that's the goal! Showing $\mathfrak{m}$ is principal is an easy application of Nakayama's lemma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question is already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818783/a-local-noetherian-ring-with-principal-maximal-ideal-implies-pir/1819402#1819402), I will give you another sketch, which uses the fact that any regular local domain is factorial. This might be an overkill, but we already have an elementary solution anyway.

The assumptions precisely state that $A$ is a one-dimensional regular local ring. In particular we have

- $A$ is factorial (a more or less non-trivial fact)
- $A$ has precisely one non-zero prime ideal, namely $\mathfrak m$ (a trivial fact).

Any irreducible element generates a non-zero prime ideal. Hence up to units, there is only one single irreducible element, say $a$. In particular any element looks like $a^n$ up to a unit. Thus any Ideal is equal to $(a^n)$, where $n$ is the minimal exponent occuring within elements of $I$.

Comment: Finally it is clear to me why the implication needed to be true!! Thank u