# Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring with unity such that every maximal ideal is principal. Then is $R$ a PIR?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, noetherian, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring with unity such that every maximal ideal is principal. Then is it true that every ideal of $R$ is principal ?

So  I think I should go like this: Suppose not. Then there is an ideal which is not principal. Consider the collection of all such ideals. It has a maximal element by Zorn's Lemma. If I can show that this maximal element is a maximal ideal then I will have the required contradiction, but I am unable to show that. Is this way correct ? Is there any other way ? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems impossible that this question *has not* been asked before because the statement is so reasonable. Oh, [look](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424551/every-maximal-ideal-is-principal-is-r-principal)! : )

Comment: @Nobody: first of all the question there is not what I ask , it was only mentioned in the accepted answer . Secondly there is no proof ( at least not the way I am approaching ) in that answer there

Comment: "Is there any other way?" [Yes, theorem 12.3](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1949-066-02/S0002-9947-1949-0031470-3/S0002-9947-1949-0031470-3.pdf). I'm commenting for a reason; this isn't a full answer addressing every facet of your question.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818783/a-local-noetherian-ring-with-principal-maximal-ideal-implies-pir

Comment: So... in a Noetherian ring, why do you need Zorn's Lemma to conclude that some collection of ideals has a maximal element?